# Criar blog do zero sem usar wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, blog

Preciso criar um blog sem usar wordpres ou qualquer outra estrutura pronta, qual linguagem eu posso utilizar e qual a maneira mais rápida de se fazer, o blog tem um formulário que irá salvar o `e-mail`, `nome completo` e `ip da pessoa`, já tenho a parte do html e css pronta preciso criar o banco de dados e a parte que faz a integração com todo o resto.

Comment: não existe nenhuma formula magica que uma pessoa possa seguir, a não ser quando optamos por usar "estruturas já prontas", claro que ai já temos a papinha praticamente feita. Mas se pretende fazer algo como um blog sem esse tipo de ajuda, vai precisar de usar muito PHP para fazer as ligações entre base de dados e o seu site

Comment: Se não me engano do DOO Framework possui - ou possuía - um exemplo de blog simples, talvez algo no FW sirva como base para você.

Comment: Usa seu html e css que já foram feitos, cria comandos em Javascript para chamar via Ajax sua API.

Answer (score 6):

**Para você ter o seu formulário funcionando, vai precisar de alguns itens:**

Em primeiro lugar a página que vai conter as caixas de texto que vai receber as informações, ou seja, a página.html:

```html
    <html>
        <head> 
            <title> Formulário </title>
        <head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h1 style="
                        margin-top:100px;"> Formulário </h1>
                    <p> </p>
                    <p class="lead"></p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <form id="cadastro" name="cadastro" method="post" action="update.php">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="
                            text-align: left;
                            margin-top:50px;">
                                    <label  for="ip">ip: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="identifiant" placeholder="Ip da pessoa" name="ip">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="nome">Nome: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome da pessoa" name="nome">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div class="form-group" style="
                            text-align: left;">
                                    <label  for="email">E-mail: </label>
                                    <input  type="text" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email da pessoa" name="email">
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Salvar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </form>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tendo o formulário, você precisa ter um banco de dados com uma tabela pra armazenar essas informações.

Você vai precisar criar um banco de dados, podemos dar a ele o nome de db_blog, nele você vai criar uma tabela que podemos chamar de blog com as colunas id, ip, nome, email.

**Vai ficar mais ou menos assim:**

```
id  |  ip  |  nome  |  email
1     123    Mariana  mariana@email.com
2     456    Pedro    pedro@email.com
```

Você pode instalar o phpMyAdmin pra criar esse banco e essa tabela.

Tendo um formulário e um banco pra armazenar as informações inseridas no formulário, só falta o site reconhecer que ele tem que pegar essas informações e armazenar no banco de dados.

**Para isso, podemos fazer uma página update.php:**

```
<?php

    $ip                   = $_POST['ip'];
    $nome                 = $_POST['nome'];
    $email                = $_POST['email'];

    $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'db_blog') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO blog VALUES ('$id', '$ip', '$nome', '$email')"; 
    mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
    mysqli_close($strcon);

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
            window.history.go(-1);
        </script>';

?>
```

Pronto, agora essa página vai pegar as informações inseridas no formulário e vai armazenar no banco de dados.

Mas como?

Simples, lembra que você colocou nas caixas de texto lá da sua página blog.html uma coisa chamada name? Pegamos esse name e armazenamos dentro de uma váriável através de post, ou seja, armazenamos o que foi digitado na caixa dentro dessa variável da página update.php.

Depois informamos qual banco de dados estamos usando e fazemos conexão com ele pra, logo em seguida, armazenar o conteúdo dessas variáveis no banco.

Por fim, fizemos um scriptzinho pra avisar ao usuário que o que ele digitou no formulário foi salvo com sucesso.

As páginas blog.html e update.php estão ligadas através de um action lá na tag form da página html que redireciona pra essa página update assim que o usuário clica em salvar, e essa página salva.

**É simples, não? Espero ter ajudado!**

Comment: Se essa resposta resolveu seu problema, não esqueça de marcar o certinho ali em baixo. :)